# tinyxml c++ using TiXmlText in storing integer data

Tags: c++, integer, tinyxml

as per the class reference  the TixmlText takes const char* values as input. 
i need to store integer data read from a text file into xml. the integer data is stored in int vector and each element of the vector is converted to const char* before passing it to Tixml text function.

```
const char* intToXmlChar(int num)
{
    stringstream abc;
    string value;
    abc<<num;
    value=abc.str();
    const char* ret_val = value.c_str();
    //char* conv_val = const_cast<char*>(ret_val);
    return ret_val;
}
```

But when i finally see the generated xml document. i get garbage values in the element where i save the number

`<timestamp>1&#x00;504</timestamp>`

how do we store integer data properly?

i had traced the where the problem was happening to an extent in the tinyxml.h

```
class TiXmlNode : public TiXmlBase
```

the function

```
void SetValue(const char * _value) {
printf(" pre ---number--- %s  using this \n",_value); //-- if the value is say 18504
 value = _value;
printf(" post ---number--- %s  using this \n",_value); //-- becomes 1&#x00;504 saved in xml
    }
```

where the value is of the same `class TiXmlNode`
being `TIXML_STRING value;`

- **Question:** Am i missing some thing
  very simple?
- **Question:** How can i
  store the integer data properly

Edit:
Thanks for the answers 
from the docs a point which i missed 
Use the compile time define:

> TIXML_USE_STL
>
> to compile one version or the other.
>   This can be passed by the compiler, or
>   set as the first line of "tinyxml.h".
>
> Note: If compiling the test code in
>   Linux, setting the environment
>   variable TINYXML_USE_STL=YES/NO will
>   control STL compilation. In the
>   Windows project file, STL and non STL
>   targets are provided. In your project,
>   **It's probably easiest to add the line
>   "#define TIXML_USE_STL" as the first
>   line of tinyxml.h.**

[Tinyxml class ref](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlText.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're compiling TinyXML with STL support (which you probably should be) `TiXmlText` also has a `std::string` constructor. As sekmet64 says, the memory allocated by the `std::string` for `c_str()` is released when the function exits so you are, in effect, returning a pointer to garbage.

However, I would strongly recommend against allocating your own memory. Instead, return a std::string (which will take care of the memory for you):

```
std::string intToXmlChar(int num)
{
    std::stringstream abc;
    std::string value;
    abc<<num;
    return abc.str();
}
```

and then pass this into the TiXmlText constructor either as

```
TiXmlText node(intToXmlChar(i));
```

or as

```
TiXmlText node(intToXmlChar(i).c_str());
```

the latter case is ok because `TiXmlText` will take a copy of the temporary string before it is destroyed.

In general stay away from conversion to a `char*` unless (or until) absolutely necessary, `std::string` is a safer and superior option the vast majority of the time.

Comment: The problem is i am not compiling with stl support. can you tell me how to do it? the library is in c and my program is in c++.

Comment: Tiny XML is a C++ library (albeit one that steers clear of the more sophisticated C++ features). To enable STL support you need to define TIXML_USE_STL. With GCC add -DTIXML_USE_STL to your command line flags, with MSVC++ add TIXML_USE_STL to the Preprocessor Definitions for your project. It is important that this define always occurs before tinyxml.h is included.

Comment: Thanks,also after you said this i was able to clearly see this point in the doc. *Note: If compiling the test code in Linux, setting the environment variable TINYXML_USE_STL=YES/NO will control STL compilation. In the Windows project file, STL and non STL targets are provided. In your project, It's probably easiest to add the line "#define TIXML_USE_STL" as the first line of tinyxml.h.*

Answer (score 2):

In C++, I can only recommend [TiCpp](http://code.google.com/p/ticpp/), a lightweight wrapper over TinyXml, with a C++ syntax.

One notable improvement: the use of `std::string` :)

**EDIT:** to get [the source](http://code.google.com/p/ticpp/source/checkout) use the following command:

```
svn checkout http://ticpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ticpp-read-only
```

Comment: i had been to that page a lot of times before. i cant seem to get the download of the the Ticpp as you put it. the only download that happens is a broken chm file.

Comment: I've used svn to retrieve the sources :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
const char* ret_val = value.c_str();
```

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/:

> The returned array points to an internal location [...], but the values in this array should not be modified in the program and are only granted to remain unchanged until the next call to a non-constant member function of the string object.

Instead you can copy the char array with `strcpy()` to a new pointer to assure that it doesn't get changed later or deleted when you exit the scope. Or better yet use the c function to convert from int straight to char*.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char* intToXmlChar(int num)
{
    char *ret_val;
    itoa(num, ret_val, 10);
    return ret_val;
}
```

I think you can't make it `const` since you have to calculate it, only when you call the function

```
const char *a = intToXmlChar(2);
```

Comment: Thanks. i wanted to avoid stdlib.h. @sekmet would you have an idea how to compile tinyxml with stl support?

Comment: Stick a `#define TIXML_USE_STL` line before you include `tinyxml.h` or stick this line at the top of `tinyxml.h`

Comment: +40 thanks sekmet i had found that when adam posted his method.